# Can Telekinesis be used to Bull Rush someone more than 5 feet?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, combat

I'm running a D&D 3.5 campaign with a BBEG who has [telekinesis](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/telekinesis.htm). During one particular encounter he tried to bull rush the fighter into a pit. The fighter's player then pointed out that since he was more than 5 feet away from the pit he was safe as the caster could not follow the target of the bull rush, preventing him from being pushed more than 5 feet.

An argument ensued and the session broke down. Normally he's not this bad, but he will not believe the spell can push more than 5 feet without some written case in the rules, because the bull rush rules in the PHB state the initiator of the bull rush must follow to push more than 5 feet.

So the question is: Does telekinesis only push 5 feet or is there an errata or mention of it pushing more than 5 feet somewhere?

Comment: Did you point out to the player that telekinesis, *by definition*, moves objects from a distance? I mean, that's literally the meaning of the word.

Comment: I assume his arguement is the caster needs to follow not the spell (aka the spell is stationary).  I wonder if he'd make the same arguement against http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#ram.  Or if that alternative example would help you or make more clear what his arguement is.  I am sketpical you'll find an example/errata so might try negating his point instead.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a Telekinetic Bull Rush can push more than 5 feet. The Bull Rush is using a moving front of telekinetic force to push, not the body of the caster. The telekinetic force can *easily* follow the fighter 5 more feet, since it has a range of hundreds of feet, and it can RAW push other things 20 feet per round.

Comment: tried that. he said it still doesnt defeat RAW.

Comment: @Novian Tell him to suck it up, because it's the DM's job to manage the rules, not the player's job. He doesn't get to ignore events he doesn't like just because he utters the syllable "RAW".

Comment: partially what caused the argument.

Comment: The question is about how Telekinetic bull rushes work, though. If there's a question about a player holding up the game and refusing to play, that will need a lot more details to answer and will probably work better as its own question.

Comment: ive given up on dealing with that issue because hes not normally so difficult. ill just let the BBEG do his thing without telekinesis. id rather not let it explode again.

There is a point where the solution to a problem is worse than giving up and changing the situation the problem exists in.

Comment: An option for the future is to not tell them what exact powers are being used for free (I'm assuming the fighter didn't somehow make a Spellcraft check to know it's Telekinesis?), and just tell them what happens and what they have to roll. Players sticking their fingers into the DM's game material can be fine if there's trust all around, but not if the player in question has a habit of metagaming using that knowledge.

Comment: @Novian What SSD said. If all you tell the player is that "a wave of force shoves him back" then there's no arguing about RAW because the player doesn't know (or *need* to know) which rules are being used.

Comment: I agree with everyone here. I'd just add one more thing: When you are pushed over an edge you are entitled a Reflex Save to hang on to the border and prevent the fall.

Comment: ive resolved his issue. even though he still says hes right hes come round to being a less of a pain in my ass about it.

and ive "Houseruled" that telekinesis works the way EVERYONE on the internet says it does.